# Allowing user to upload to their own channel using youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Youtube's api ToS state that we must allow a user to upload a video to their own account or to our youtube application account. What would be the proper process for doing this? The code snippets refer to using one's own account (e.g. api key and secret key). Will these work for uploading to the user's account?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want users to upload video on your channel, what they need is your OAuth token. This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198093/api-upload-video-in-php-to-a-specific-channel) also have an information about your problem.

This [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#obtainingaccesstokens) will explain you on how to obtain an OAuth access token. It contains sample code that you can copy/follow.

For more information, you can check these tutorials:

- [How to Authenticate & upload videos to YouTube Channel in PHP](http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-authenticate-upload-videos-to-youtube-channel-in-php_974.html)
- [PHP server-side YouTube V3 OAuth API video upload guide](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide)