# Thumbnail set endpoint throws BackendError on larger uploads

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm using the thumbnail set [api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/thumbnails/set) to upload a thumbnail.  On larger thumbnail uploads I'm getting this error

```
The service youtube has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nBackend Error [500]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError]
```

- I'm using google-api-dotnet-client version 1.9.2.
- I've confirmed the channel has custom thumbnails enabled and it works
  on smaller thumbnails
- I've tried changing the chunk size to see if that helps but no luck.

Any ideas why?

```
var setMediaUpload = _apiService.Thumbnails.Set(videoId, new MemoryStream(imageBytes), "image/png");
setMediaUpload.OauthToken = _accessToken;

var result = setMediaUpload.Upload();
if (result.Status != UploadStatus.Completed)
{
....
```

Comment: I would suggest to try the solution in this related [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18666666/5995040), the workaround is through the POST request and see how the code will behave. But if this still fails, you might want to report it as a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)) in the issue tracker. Hope this helps.

Comment: what happens if you send the request again?   500 is normally a server hiccup.   how big is the picture you are sending?    the default thumbnail image for a video resource is typically 120px by 90px, and the default thumbnail image for a channel resource is typically 88px by 88px.